# ADODB connection to firebird

Tags: adodb, testcomplete, firebird2.5

How to I connect to firebird database with ADODB connection?
I'm using testcomplete to test application runing on firebird.
following doesn't work...

```
Conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
constr = 'User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=C:\..\Sample.fdb;DataSource=Local;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet Size=8192;ServerType=0;'

Conn.ConnectionString = constr;
qrery = 'Select Count(*) FROM XX ';

recSet = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
recSet.Open(qrery,Conn,3 /* adOpenStatic */, 1 /* adLockReadOnly */,1);

Log.Message(recSet.Fields.Item(0).Value  );

recSet.Close();
```

Get following error

> The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the connection after creating it and before making a query:

```
  var Conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
  var constr = 'User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=C:\\..\\Sample.fdb;DataSource=Local;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet Size=8192;ServerType=0;'

  Conn.ConnectionString = constr;
  var qrery = 'Select Count(*) FROM XX ';

  Conn.Open(); // Openning the connection

  var recSet = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
  recSet.Open(qrery,Conn,3 /* adOpenStatic */, 1 /* adLockReadOnly */,1);

  Log.Message(recSet.Fields.Item(0).Value  );

  recSet.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks, Also found since this is jScript it should be C:\\..\\Sample.fdb